# php(codeigniter) set default value with form helper

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter

I have a form that will be used for different action(inserting and updating). I use `isset` function for updating purpose. This is the **complete** code :

```
<div id="form_daftar">
    <?php echo form_open($action) ?>
        <?php
            if($action === 'backend/pengurus/add')
                $pengurus['email'] = '';
        ?>
        <p id="input_nama">
            Nama : <?php echo form_input('txt_nama', isset($pengurus['nama'])?$pengurus['nama']:"");?>
        </p>
        <p id="input_email">
            Email : <?php echo form_input('txt_email', 
            isset($pengurus['email'])?$pengurus['email']:"");?>
        </p>
        <p id="input_password">
            Password : <?php echo form_password('txt_pengurus');?>
        </p>
        <p id="input_alamat">
            Alamat : <?php echo form_input('txt_alamat', isset($pengurus['alamat'])?$pengurus['alamat']:"");?>
        </p>
        <p id="input_tanggal_lahir">
            Tanggal Lahir : <input type="text" id="datepicker" name="datepicker"
            value="<?php echo isset($pengurus['tanggal_lahir'])?$pengurus['tanggal_lahir']:""?>"/>  
        </p>

        <?php 
            $action === 'backend/pengurus/add' ? $label = "Daftarkan Pengurus" : $label = "Update Data Pengurus";
            echo form_submit('btn_insert', $label);
        ?>
    <?php echo form_close(); ?>
</div>
```

However, i got a weird bug so the isset is not working correctly. So, i tried to add this piece of code (snippet from above) :

```
<?php
   if($action === 'backend/pengurus/add')
      $pengurus['email'] = '';
?>
```

However, the `$pengurus['email']` is not recognized, although its recognized in the form below this code (look the complete code).

What should i do?

Any help is appreciated, please just ask me if you dont understand my question (English is not my native languange). Thanks:D

Comment: @IgorS. well i dont tell you the detail because it weeird (and hard to say). My form_input just have a default value (i dont know where that value from, i might have to copy the entire code here to fix that). So, i think i just have to unset the $pengurus's value if the $action is for inserting :D

Answer (score 3):

for setting default values for form inputs in CI, you use set_value(), like:

```
<?php echo form_input('txt_nama', set_value('txt_nama', ''));?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but i also need the isset for updating purpose

Answer (score 1):

It is simple do this

when you load you form for insertion you can add an empty array
and pass it to form

```
$pengurus['name'] = '';
$pengurus['email'] = '';
$pengurus['blah'] = '';

$data['pengurus']   =   $pengurus;

$this->load->view('form',$pengurus);
```

And when you load form for update you can fill these

```
$pengurus['name']   =   $row->name;
$pengurus['email']  =   $row->email;
$pengurus['blah']   =   $row->blah;

$data['pengurus']   =   $pengurus;

$this->load->view('form',$pengurus);
```

//$row is an object retrieved with model

Now in the form you can do this

```
echo form_input('name', set_value('name',$pengurus['name']));
```

`set_value` takes 2nd parameter for default value. the default value for 
insertion is '' and for updation is some `name`. When you submit form
and it fails it will check for the value you provided before submitting
if not found than it will display the default(for insertion '' and for 
updation row->name). Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for your help. I tried this in my controller, but it still not working :(   

if ($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE)
  {
   $data['pengurus']['email'] = '';
   $this->load->view('template/header_v');
   $this->load->view('backend/pengurus_form_v', $data);
  }

Comment: @BlazeTama what is the error try putting `$pangurus['email'] = 'test@gmail.com'`

Comment: Theres no error, the default value (which i dont know where from) is still there. I tried it, and the value is not changed at all @@

Comment: do you mean when you are loading form on failed validation the default value is being displayed?